# different ways of calling class method with button clicks

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I am exploring how to call class methods in PyQt applications. As a test, I created a widget that initializes a worker, puts it on a separate thread, and starts the thread. I also created two buttons:

1. The left button connects to the `run` function of the worker directly
2. The right button connects to a widget method that calls the worker `run` function

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from time import sleep


class Worker(QObject):

    worker_finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        print("Sleeping")
        for ii in range(5):
            print(ii)
            sleep(1)
        print("Finished sleeping")


class MainApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._threads = []
        
        #Create the worker
        self.worker = Worker()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        #Move the worker on the thread and start
        self.put_on_thread_and_start(self.worker)

        #This button calls worker.run() directly
        button = QPushButton("Call \"\"run\"\" method directly")
        button.clicked.connect(self.worker.run)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        #This button calls a widget method, which calls worker.run()
        button = QPushButton("Call \"\"run\"\" method through this widget class method")
        button.clicked.connect(self.make_the_worker_run)
        layout.addWidget(button)

    def put_on_thread_and_start(self, worker_class):
        myThread = QThread()
        self._threads.append(myThread)
        worker_class.moveToThread(myThread)
        print("Starting thread...")
        myThread.start()

    def make_the_worker_run(self):
        self.worker.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I click the left button, the worker executes in the background, as expected. However, when I click the right button the widget freezes until the worker has finished running. What's the difference between the two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a signal is emitted to a function (slot) and that signal is emitted, Qt detects if the signal emission and the receiving objects are in the same thread. If they are *not*, the slot is executed in the receiver's thread and control is immediately returned in the sender instead. This is what allows to use threads on Qt without blocking the "main Qt thread" (which is responsible of keeping the UI responsive).

A very important thing to understand is that Qt is able to detect what thread emitted the signal and on what thread the *slot* is, then it decides if the slot can be directly executed or not.

In your first case, the button (which is going to emit the signal) and the `self.worker.run` are on different threads and Qt knows that when it tries to call `run`; the result is that the function will be executed in the other thread.

In the second case, Qt only knows about `make_the_worker_run`, which from its perspective is in the same thread of the button: Qt doesn't know anything about what you actually do in that function. The fact that `run` is in a method of an object that has been moved to another thread doesn't mean anything, and the result is that the function will be executed in the main thread, hence the blocking.

Read more about this topic on the Qt docs about [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Answer (score 2):

There is an incorrect conception of how threads, QThread, signals, etc. work.

When a QObject is moved to a QThread it only tells the Qt eventloop that if it invokes a slot of that QObject it must be executed in the thread that manages the QThread (if the Qt::QueuedConnection or Qt::AutoConnection flag is used in the connection). And how does the Qt eventloop invoke the functions? Well, for this use the signals, timers, QMetaObject::invokedMethod, QEvents, etc.

The above explains why the first method works: By using the clicked signal to invoke "run" it notifies the eventloop that it should invoke the method, and using the previous rule it will invoke the thread that manages the QThread.

In the second method instead you are invoking it directly in the main thread which blocks the eventloop of the main thread freezing the GUI.